# binding ctrl+x+return using jquery hotkeys plugin

Tags: jquery, hotkeys

I am trying to bind <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> key combination on the keydown event using the jquery hotkeys plugin but its not happening. Although, i am able to bind <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> key.

source code:

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown','ctrl+x+return',function () {  
        alert('bounded');
    });
```

Comment: Please provide your source code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but jquery.hotkeys.js is where the problem is.
The plugin needs to introduce a time delay system into the plugin to add true support for 3+ key combinations.

I recommend that you try a different key combination other than <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>